# Layout returning wrong keys in custom keyboard Android jetpack compose

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, user-input

I'm facing an issue with my Android Compose keyboard layout where the symbol layout is displaying the "qwerty" label instead of the expected symbols. I've tried troubleshooting, but I can't seem to figure out what's causing this problem. Here are the details:

I have implemented a custom Android Compose keyboard with two layout states: "qwerty" and "symbols." The idea is to switch between these layouts to input either regular text or symbols.

When I switch to the "symbols" layout and press a key, it correctly displays the symbol character on the key itself, but the character entered into the text field is still the "qwerty" character, which is unexpected.

I've verified that the layout state switches correctly to "symbols" when the layout switch key is pressed.

In the symbolsLayout array, I've defined the symbol characters I want to display for each key.

The CustomKey composable, which handles key presses, seems to be aware of the currentLayout state to determine whether to display symbols or qwerty characters.

Here is my code.
**CustomKeyboard**

```
package com.soloftech.keyboard.presentation.layout

import android.content.Context
import android.os.Vibrator
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.DisposableEffect
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.res.colorResource
import androidx.compose.ui.res.dimensionResource
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.soloftech.keyboard.R
import com.soloftech.keyboard.data.keyboard_layout.Key
import com.soloftech.keyboard.data.keyboard_layout.LayoutState
import com.soloftech.keyboard.data.layout.qwertyLayout
import com.soloftech.keyboard.data.layout.symbolsLayout
import com.soloftech.keyboard.domain.KeyboardVisibilityProvider
import com.soloftech.keyboard.domain.vibrate
import com.soloftech.keyboard.presentation.service.CustomImeService

@Composable
fun CustomKeyboard(
    imeService: CustomImeService?,
    vibrator: Vibrator? = null,
    context: Context?
) {

// Declare the current layout as a mutable state
    var currentLayout by remember { mutableStateOf(LayoutState.Qwerty) }

    // Use the currentLayout to determine which keys to display
    val keys: Array<Array<Key>> = when (currentLayout) {
        LayoutState.Qwerty -> qwertyLayout
        LayoutState.Symbols -> symbolsLayout
    }

    val onLayoutSwitchClick: () -> Unit = {
        currentLayout = if (currentLayout == LayoutState.Qwerty) {
            LayoutState.Symbols
        } else {
            LayoutState.Qwerty
        }
    }

    // Detect keyboard visibility changes
    var isKeyboardVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    KeyboardVisibilityProvider { isVisible ->
        isKeyboardVisible = isVisible
        if (!isKeyboardVisible) {
            // Keyboard is hidden, switch back to qwerty layout
            currentLayout = LayoutState.Qwerty
        }
    }

    DisposableEffect(isKeyboardVisible) {
        if (!isKeyboardVisible) {
            // Keyboard is hidden, switch back to qwerty layout
            currentLayout = LayoutState.Qwerty
        }
        onDispose { }
    }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(colorResource(id = R.color.KeyboardBackground))
            .padding(vertical = 6.dp)
    ) {
        Column(
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
        ) {
            keys.forEachIndexed { rowIndex, row ->
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(
                            horizontal = if (rowIndex == 2) 16.dp else dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.key_marginH).value.dp,
                            vertical = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.key_marginV).value.dp
                        ),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
                ) {
                    row.forEach { key ->
//
//                        val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
//                        object : Runnable {
//                            override fun run() {
//                                Log.d(TAG, "run: ${key.label}")
//                                handler.postDelayed(this, 5000)
//                            }
//                        }.run()

                        CustomKey(
                            key = key,
                            onKeyPressed = {
                                vibrate(vibrator)
                                imeService?.doSomethingWith(key, false)
                            },
                            onLongKeyPressed = {
                                vibrate(vibrator)
                                imeService?.doSomethingWith(key, true)
                            },
                            onLongKeyPressedEnd = {
                                imeService?.longPressedStops()
                            },
                            onLayoutSwitchClick = onLayoutSwitchClick,
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(horizontal = 3.dp)
                                .weight(key.weight),
                            context = context
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


@Preview
@Composable
fun CustomKeyboardPreview() {
    CustomKeyboard(
        imeService = null,
        vibrator = null,
        context = null
    )
}
```

**CustomKey**

```
package com.soloftech.keyboard.presentation.layout


import android.content.Context
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.detectTapGestures
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.clip
import androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.pointerInput
import androidx.compose.ui.res.colorResource
import androidx.compose.ui.res.dimensionResource
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.IntOffset
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import com.soloftech.keyboard.R
import com.soloftech.keyboard.data.keyboard_layout.Key
import com.soloftech.keyboard.domain.playSound
import com.soloftech.keyboard.presentation.service.CustomImeService


@Composable
fun CustomKey(
    key: Key,
    onKeyPressed: (Key) -> Unit,
    onLongKeyPressed: (Key) -> Unit,
    onLongKeyPressedEnd: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier,
    onLayoutSwitchClick: () -> Unit,
    context: Context?,
) {
    val isPopupVisible = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    val keyColor = if (key.isSpecialCharacter) {
        colorResource(id = R.color.SpecialKeyBackground)
    } else {
        colorResource(id = R.color.KeyBackground)
    }

    val textColor = colorResource(id = R.color.KeyTextColor)

    val keyShape = when (key.label) {
        "?123", "Done", "ABC" -> RoundedCornerShape(36.dp)
        else -> RoundedCornerShape(6.dp)
    }

    val iconResourceId = if (CustomImeService.isCapsEnabled && key.alternativeIcon != null) {
        key.alternativeIcon
    } else {
        key.icon
    }
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .clip(keyShape)
            .background(keyColor)
            .height(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.key_height).value.dp)
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectTapGestures(
                    onLongPress = {
                        onLongKeyPressed(key)
                    },
                    onPress = {
                        awaitRelease()
                        onLongKeyPressedEnd()
                    },
                    onTap = {
                        isPopupVisible.value = true
                        if (context != null) {
                            playSound(context = context)
                        }
                        if (key.label == "?123" || key.label == "ABC") onLayoutSwitchClick()
                        else onKeyPressed(key)
                        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
                            isPopupVisible.value = false
                        }, 250)
                    }
                )
            },
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        if (iconResourceId != null && key.contentDescription != null) {
            Icon(
                painter = painterResource(id = iconResourceId),
                contentDescription = key.contentDescription,
                tint = textColor,
                modifier = Modifier.size(26.dp)
            )
        } else {
            when (key.label) {
                "?123", "ABC", "Space" -> AutoResizedText(
                    text = key.label,
                    color = textColor
                )

                else -> Text(
                    text = key.label,
                    color = textColor,
                    fontSize = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.key_textSize).value.sp
                )
            }

        }

        if (isPopupVisible.value && key.shouldShowPopUp) {
            PopupScreen(
                label = key.label,
                offset = IntOffset(x = 0, y = -90)
            )
        }
    }
}


@Preview
@Composable
fun CustomKeyPreview() {
    CustomKey(
        key = Key("f", 1F),
        onKeyPressed = {},
        onLongKeyPressed = {},
        modifier = Modifier,
        context = null,
        onLongKeyPressedEnd = {},
        onLayoutSwitchClick = {}
    )
}
```

And here is custom IME.

```
package com.soloftech.keyboard.presentation.service


import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.os.Vibrator
import android.os.VibratorManager
import android.text.TextUtils
import android.view.KeyEvent
import android.view.View
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getSystemService
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelStore
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelStoreOwner
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewTreeLifecycleOwner
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner
import androidx.savedstate.SavedStateRegistry
import androidx.savedstate.SavedStateRegistryController
import androidx.savedstate.SavedStateRegistryOwner
import androidx.savedstate.setViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner
import com.soloftech.keyboard.data.keyboard_layout.Key
import com.soloftech.keyboard.presentation.layout.CustomKeyboard


class CustomImeService : InputMethodService(), LifecycleOwner, ViewModelStoreOwner,
    SavedStateRegistryOwner {

    companion object {
        var isCapsEnabled = false
    }

    private var isBackspaceKeyPressed = false
    private val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    private var deleteCharacterRunnable = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            val inputConnection = currentInputConnection

            if (inputConnection != null && isBackspaceKeyPressed) {
                val selectedText: CharSequence? = inputConnection.getSelectedText(0)

                if (selectedText != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(selectedText)) {
                    // There is selected text, so delete it
                    inputConnection.commitText("", 1)
                } else {
                    // No selected text, delete the character to the left
                    inputConnection.deleteSurroundingText(1, 0)
                }

                // Schedule the next deletion after 100 ms
                handler.postDelayed(this, 100)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateInputView(): View {
        val view = ComposeKeyboardView(this)

        window!!.window!!.decorView.let { decorView ->
            ViewTreeLifecycleOwner.set(decorView, this)
            ViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner.set(decorView, this)
            view.setViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner(this)
        }
        view.let {
            ViewTreeLifecycleOwner.set(it, this)
            ViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner.set(it, this)
            it.setViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner(this)
        }
        return view
    }


    fun doSomethingWith(
        key: Key,
        isLongPressed: Boolean
    ) {
        when (key.label) {
            "Space" -> {
                if (isLongPressed) {
                    val imm = getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
                    imm.showInputMethodPicker()
                } else {
                    currentInputConnection.commitText(" ", 1)
                }
            }

            "CAPS" -> {
                isCapsEnabled = !isCapsEnabled
            }

            "Done" -> {
                currentInputConnection.sendKeyEvent(
                    KeyEvent(
                        KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER
                    )
                )
            }

            "Delete" -> {
                if (isLongPressed) {
                    // Start character deletions when the key is long-pressed
                    if (!isBackspaceKeyPressed) {
                        isBackspaceKeyPressed = true
                        deleteCharacterRunnable.run()
                    }
                } else {
                    val inputConnection = currentInputConnection

                    if (inputConnection != null) {
                        val selectedText: CharSequence? = inputConnection.getSelectedText(0)

                        if (selectedText != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(selectedText)) {
                            // There is selected text, so delete it
                            inputConnection.commitText("", 1)
                        } else {
                            // No selected text, delete the character to the left
                            inputConnection.deleteSurroundingText(1, 0)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            else -> {
                val inputConnection = currentInputConnection
                if (inputConnection != null) {
                    val label = key.label
                    val uppercaseValue = if (isCapsEnabled) label.uppercase() else label
                    inputConnection.commitText(uppercaseValue, 1)
                }
            }

        }
    }

    fun longPressedStops() {
        // Stop character deletions when the key is released
        isBackspaceKeyPressed = false
        handler.removeCallbacks(deleteCharacterRunnable)
    }

    //SaveStateRegistry Methods
    private val savedStateRegistryVar = SavedStateRegistryController.create(this)

    override val savedStateRegistry: SavedStateRegistry
        get() = savedStateRegistryVar.savedStateRegistry

    //Lifecycle Methods
    private var lifecycleRegistry: LifecycleRegistry = LifecycleRegistry(this)

    override fun getLifecycle(): Lifecycle {
        return lifecycleRegistry
    }

    private fun handleLifecycleEvent(event: Lifecycle.Event) =
        lifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(event)

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        savedStateRegistryVar.performRestore(null)
        lifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
    }


    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
    }

    //ViewModelStore Methods
    private val store = ViewModelStore()

    override fun getViewModelStore(): ViewModelStore = store

}

@SuppressLint("ViewConstructor")
class ComposeKeyboardView(private val imeService: CustomImeService) :
    AbstractComposeView(imeService) {

    @Composable
    override fun Content() {
        CustomKeyboard(
            imeService = imeService,
            vibrator = vibrator,
            context = context
        )
    }

    private val vibrator: Vibrator by lazy {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            val vibratorManager = getSystemService(context, VibratorManager::class.java)
            vibratorManager?.defaultVibrator ?: getSystemService(context, Vibrator::class.java)
        } else {
            getSystemService(context, Vibrator::class.java)
        } as Vibrator
    }

}
```

I also runned a test in which i runned a runnable every 5 seconds and that log the keys of current layout and i noticed that it first returs qwerty layouy tham sybols layiut keys. MAybe that is the issue. HOW can i solve this.
Thanks.